# Identifying limits of integration in 3D from a cylindrical coordinate transform

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, graph-limits

**Problem**

I am trying to compute the volume of the region bounded above by the hemisphere $z=(a^2-x^2-y^2)^{0.5}$ and below by the cone $z=(x^2+y^2)^{0.5}$

I know that the question is solvable using cylindrical and spherical coordinates and so I was trying both when I ran into a problem whilst attempting to solve using cylindrical coordinates.

The problem that I have is that I don’t seem to be identifying the correct limits for the problem.

The correct solution is as follows:

[image]

However, to me, this looks to only cover half of the shaded region. It feels natural to me to multiply this integral by 2 so that we consider the values of r between $r=\frac{-a}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $r=0$ which don’t seem to be considered in the limits of the solution integral.

I was wondering if anyone could explain where the gap in my intuition is here? To me it feels as though this integral neglects the left half of the shaded region in the graph above.

Comment: "this looks to only cover half of the shaded region". This part is incorrect, other part is covered by rotation due to $\theta \in[0;2\pi)$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: It's very good to practice changing coordinates, and as such it is a good idea to try out cylindrical here. But if your goal was only to calculate the integral, not to practice doing integrals, then spherical coordinates would be a _lot_ more natural for this region. Even though the integration factor tends to be more complicated ($r^2\sin\phi$ as opposed to just $r$), that's usually worth it even with more advanced integrands, as in my experience the very simple bounds usually makes for a worthwhile trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there a good way of generally spotting when cylindrical or spherical co-ordinates will be the more appropriate substitution? I know that generally shapes like hemispheres and cones work well with spherical coordinates but I often find it hard to make a good guess as to which change of coordinates will work best in general @Arthur

Comment: @FD_bfa If you know what the coordinate grids look like in the different coordinate systems, you usually want a coordinate system where the boundaries of the region align with that grid as much as possible. However, if, say, the region is very simple in spherical coordinates, but the integrand is very simple in Cartesian coordinates, there is no hard rule to say which one will ultimately be best (I would personally try spherical first). Ignoring both of them and going for cylindrical would likely be a bad idea, though.

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates, you could also write it as $ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{a / \sqrt2} \int_0^z r ~ dr ~ dz ~ d\theta~ + ~$ $ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{a / \sqrt2}^a \int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}} r ~ dr ~ dz ~ d\theta$

Comment: Your first thought may be that there are two split integrals to evaluate and so not ideal, but very quickly you may realize this is as fast as the single triple integral you wrote, if not faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @IvanKaznacheyeu for your comment helping me to identify my mistake.

Despite the fact that theta imposes no restrictions on the region, we cannot reduce this to a 2 dimensional integral as $\theta$ causes a rotation about the $z$ axis.

Therefore, the rotation for $\theta$ betweeen $[0,2\pi]$ means that the left hand side of the region is covered by the integral in the image and there is no need for us to double the value of V calculated there as this will lead to an incorrect answer (doubling the actual volume).